# How do I get mput (Windows FTP) to not overwrite files?

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp

I have a directory on my local system, lets say C:\dir. I'm writing a batch script to upload the contents of that directory to my server. Here's the script:

```
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open ftp.chintanparikh.x10.mx
[username]
[password]
lcd C:\dir
cd  somedir/dir
binary
mput "*.*"
```

Is it possible to somehow change mput to not overwrite files? Currently, it seems to overwrite files with the same name. I'm planning on getting this to run automatically, once a day, hence why I'd rather it didn't overwrite the files.

Cheers,
Chintan

Comment: Maybe you should be looking at a backup tool like rsync or unison? Or perhaps you need a web-site updating tool that updates files if the local copy has a more recent modification date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule) can be used to schedule updates using FTP.

Normally you want files to be overwritten if, and only if, the local copy has a more recent modification time. See WinSCP's [synchronize command](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize)