# free ftp client application with sync option

Tags: ftp

i use currently filezilla for ftp client . but when upload  a folder that same exists on remote server. all files sent.
What software could I schedule it to sync my local folder  to a folder on my FTP account?

Comment: WinSCP. See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/424866/52492) to a slightly different question.

Comment: You need to specify operating system for anyone to be able to answer without guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SyncBackSE

http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbse-features.html